# Issues creating an Ionic project

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

When I tried to create a new Ionic project it shows me an error:

```
**Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:67:26)**
```

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : goto terminal  with  help of shortcut in ubntu **ctrl + alt + t**

step 2 : then type **sudo gedit ~/.ionic/config.json**

step 3 : and remove below lines from ionic configration file

`export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8888"                             export HTTPS_PROXY="https://proxy.example.com:8888"                                     export IONIC_HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8888"`

step 4 : save ionic/config.json file and exit

step 5 : and try again for downloading project